# Tapping Tab bar to filter list Flutter

Tags: list, arraylist, flutter, dart, filtering

I am trying to filter items from an array and create a new one out of it. When a user taps on one of the tabs, the list sorts the products into its categories(ie: When the dinner tab is selected, all products labeled as category "Dinner" will show) from there organize into sub categories (Chicken, Beef, Oxtail). I am not sure where I am going wrong here. Here is what I have so far:

Tab Bar

```
TabBar(
                    onTap: _changedDropDownItem,
                    indicatorColor: buddiesGreen,
                    labelColor: buddiesPurple,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    // isScrollable: true,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.medkit), text: "Dinner"),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.heart), text: "Desserts"),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Taste"),
                      Tab(
                        icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.home),
                        text: "More",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Then I use these methods to get the categories from the tab bar:

```
 void _tabBarItemsTapped(int newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedCustomerType = newValue;
    });
    _tabBarFilterSwitch(newValue);
    print(_selectedCustomerType);
  }


  void _tabBarFilterSwitch(filterNumb) {
    if (filterNumb == 0) {
      _dropdownList = _usage;
    } else if (filterNumb == 1) {
      _dropdownList = _productType;
    } else if (filterNumb == 2) {
      _dropdownList = _productType;
    } else if (filterNumb == 3) {
      _dropdownList = _productType;
    }
    print(_dropdownList);
  }
```

Here is a data model I'm pulling down:

```
{
    "resId":123,
 “image”: “    'assets/ChocolateCake.jpg',
“productType”: “Dinner”
“type”: “main”
   “sizes” : 
   [
       {“size”:1,
        “price”:$2.99},
       {“size”:3,
        "quantity”: $4.99}
  ]
}
```

I am trying to tap the tab that would trigger a switch case. This switch chase will update the list:

```
void _filterProductList(int value, productList, filter) {
    List tempProducts = [];

    switch (value) {
      case 0:
          for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        tempProducts.add(productList[i].category.contains(filter[i]));
            // tempProducts = productList
            // tempProducts.
            productList =[];
            productList = tempProducts;
            print(tempProducts[i].name);

          }
        break;
      case 1:
            for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        tempProducts.add(productList[i].category.contains(filter[i]));
            // tempProducts = productList
            // tempProducts.
            productList =[];
            productList = tempProducts;
            print(tempProducts[i].name);
          }
        break;
      case 2:
            for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        tempProducts.add(productList[i].category.contains(filter[i]));
            // tempProducts = productList
            // tempProducts.
            productList =[];
            productList = tempProducts;
            print(tempProducts[i].name);
          }
        break;
      case 3:
            for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
        tempProducts.add(productList[i].category.contains(filter[i]));
            // tempProducts = productList
            // tempProducts.
            productList =[];
            productList = tempProducts;
            print(tempProducts[i].name);
          }
        break;
    }
    return;

  }
```

And presents like:

```
Container(
              child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            itemCount: _prodType.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, ii) {
              _filterProductList(filterNumb, productList, _dropdownList);
              return Container(child: _buildProduct(context, ii));
            },
          )),
```

Instead of updating the list with every tap, it just seems like nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the hi you need to use `setState`.

`productList = tempProducts` should be:

```
setState(()=>productList = tempProducts);
```

Also, the widget should be a `stateful` widget.

Comment: Its also about filtering the list to match the categories